# How do I access the function that owns a Function.prototype extension?

Tags: javascript, prototype

I am attempting to create a Function extension to debounce any function (if the function is called multiple times in rapid succession, only execute it one time, and optimally return a cached value).

I intend to use it inside a UI framework, but I want it to be portable. The code I have so far is as follows:

```
Function.prototype.debounce = function()
{
    var originalFunction = this; //this should be 'clickButton' in the example implementation
    var originalArguments = arguments;

    function debouncedFunction()
    {
        var originalContext = this;
        return originalFunction.apply(originalContext,originalArguments)
    }

    if(this.__DEBOUNCEDVALUE === undefined)
    {
        this.__DEBOUNCEDVALUE = debouncedFunction();
        if(this.__DEBOUNCEDVALUE === undefined)
            this.__DEBOUNCEDVALUE = null;
        setTimeout(function(){originalFunction.__DEBOUNCEDVALUE = undefined},1000);
    }

    return this;
}
```

Next, I defined a generic function, "clickButton", which looks like this:

```
function clickButton()
{
    document.getElementById('log').innerHTML += "<br/>Clicked "+arguments[1];
    return "some value";
}
```

When I call `clickButton.debounce(3,4)`, it works. It only logs to the document one per second, but returns every time it's called.

However, when I call it through a listener (`buttons[i].addEventListener('click',clickButton.debounce)`), the `originalFunction` variable is set to the button, and not to the function. Not a big surprise. How do I get a reference to `clickButton` from within debounce in this example?

Edit:
I have tried switching to using defineProperty, which allows me to save the context and function at access time. Unfortunately, this does not work in all cases (putting it into a tap handler in Sencha Touch causes a function to be called within the Window scope). This is closer, but still unacceptable.

```
Object.defineProperty(Function.prototype,'debounce',{get: function()
    {
        var originalFunction = this;
        var execute = function()
        {
            if(originalFunction.__DEBOUNCEDVALUE === undefined)
            {
                originalFunction.__DEBOUNCEDVALUE = originalFunction.apply(this,arguments);
                if(originalFunction.__DEBOUNCEDVALUE === undefined)
                    originalFunction.__DEBOUNCEDVALUE = null;
                setTimeout(function()
                    {
                        originalFunction.__DEBOUNCEDVALUE = undefined;
                        console.log("Reset");
                    },5000);
            }
            else
                console.log("Return cached value");

            return originalFunction.__DEBOUNCEDVALUE;
        }
        return execute;

    }});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can only be done via some method of binding the function object to the `debounce`.

One way is using `.bind`

```
buttons[i].addEventListener('click',clickButton.debounce.bind(clickButton)),
```

---

Another way is to pass an anonymous function that closes over the `clickButton`.

```
buttons[i].addEventListener('click',function(e) {
    return clickButton.debounce.apply(clickButton, arguments);

        // The following would suffice for this example:
    // return clickButton.debounce(e);
}),
```

---

But aside from these sorts of techniques, `debounce` will have no memory of the object from which it was referenced when passed to `addEventListener`.